# R Graphics device not responding

Tags: java, r, rserve

I am using `java` with `Rserve` to generate a phylogenetic tree.

```
RConnection r=null;
r = new RConnection();
r.eval("library(ape)");
r.eval("dev.new(plot(rtree(10)));dev.off()");
```

As you can see in the image provided below the code works but the Graphics Device is not responding.
What am I missing to keep the Graphics Device responsive?

[image]

Comment: `dev.new(plot(rtree(10)))` actually opens 2 plots (no idea why). the later one does not show anything.

Comment: does `r.eval("dev.new();plot(rtree(10))")` solve your problem? I've tried it on R and it seem to open a placeholder plot, then fill it with your plot! Hope it helps

Comment: `r.eval("dev.new();plot(rtree(10))")` returns an empty plot still not responding